# last part of proof of schur zassenhaus theorem.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Theorem states-
Let $G$ be a finite group of order $mn$ and $N$ be a normal subgroup of order $n$, then schur zassenhaus states that there exist a complement of $N$ in $G$ of order $m$ and all such are conjugate if more than one.

The proof i have gone through are very long, but every proof is reduction upto case where $N$ is proved abelian and then some long transversals based continuation of proof(as in Isaacs & also Robinson , too long and confusing), but in a paper by Conrad he states than rest of proof can be done by cohomology theory(the vanishing of $H^2(G/N,N$), he says.) I did self read homology and cohomology from Rotman a few months back but will need a quick revision though. So if somebody can tell me the main steps how the proof proceed via cohomology argument, it will be a huge help. I hope proof via cohomology will be much shorter and elegant , is it?
Thanks

Comment: The horrible transveral-based proof can be rewritten in a quite elegant and understandable way, see for example section 3.3 in the book "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher.

Comment: A proof using cohomology could not be regarded as shorter, because it depends on so much machinery. It is arguably more elegant, but IMO that is only because it is hiding the technicalities behind some more sophisticated language. If you analyse the cohomological proof in enough detail to find out what the elements of the complements  are or what is the conjugating element, then you will come up with the same formula as is used in the transversal-based proof. (I don't find it horrible, but I prefer constructive proofs.)

Comment: For future visitors, the proof that @j.p. mentions is sketched here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666460/proof-of-the-schur-zassenhaus-theorem-without-using-homological-algebra "There is an elementary proof which goes back to Gaschütz. It can be found in the book "The theory of finite groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher (see 3.3.1 and 6.2.1). The idea is an "average trick"..."